# Deploying caffe RNNs

Tags: c++, caffe, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to deploy a caffe model containing a RNN layer. The issue I'm having is how to compute the output from the network. My assumption was that I could call

```
net->Forward();
```

to update the network and then

```
net->output_blobs()[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[x];
```

once every timestep to read the output. However, using a constant input and then running "`net-Forward()`" multiple times does not affect the output as one would expect. I've tried to use different weights/biases, which changes the output, but no matter what configuration I'm using the output will still be static. Does anyone know what the proper procedure for deploying caffe RNNs with C++ is?

Edit:

This was tested with a single neuron RNN layer like below.

model.prototxt:

```
layer {
    name: "input"
    type: "Input"
    top: "states"
    input_param {
        shape: {
            dim: 1
            dim: 1
        }
    }
}

input: "clip"
input_shape { dim: 1 dim: 1 dim: 1}

layer {
    name: "rnn"
    type: "RNN"
    top: "rnn"
    bottom: "clip"
    bottom: "states"
    recurrent_param {
        num_output: 1
    }
}
```

And the .cpp:

```
caffe::Blob<float>* input_layer = test_net->input_blobs()[0];
float* input_data;
input_data = input_layer->mutable_cpu_data();

input_data[0] = 1.0;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    test_net->Forward();
    cout << "Ouput: " << net->output_blobs().back()->mutable_cpu_data()[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: This might require a bit more code.